# ActiveRecord and might belongs_to

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have a pair of data types where every `X` may have many `Y`, and each `Y` has at most one `X`.

In the database, I'd visualized this as

```
 CREATE TABLE xs (
   id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
 );
 CREATE TABLE ys (
   id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   x_id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES xs (id) -- may be NULL
 );
```

Using ActiveRecord, it's easy for me to that every `X` `has_many` `Y`, but how do I express that every `Y` has at most one `X`?  My impression that `belongs_to` would normally work, but I'm not sure how it'll like the situation when `x_id` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. Y should have a `belongs_to :x`.

If `x_id` is not present, `y.x` will return `nil`.

Having a belongs_to doesn't mean that if the value is not present, everything will blow up.

Comment: cool thanks.  Everything I'd read said that `belongs_to` was for one-to-one or many-to-one relationships, and didn't mention many-to-one-or-zero. :)